# how I find a control in datalist

Tags: asp.net

[image]I have taken a datalist in my asp.net project which contains some picture and picture name. Now I want to show each picture in another page after. It means if any user will click on the picture then picture will open with it's details in another page.So I want to know that how I find a control in datalist.
In following picture of datalist I want to click on picture name like Jai Ho and It will open in another page.
[image]

Comment: Can you show the markup of your DataList and the code that you are using to bind the data to the DataList?

Comment: I have added the coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `OnClientClick` property of Link Button.
In `<asp:LinkButton>` tag add following code

```
OnClientClick="javascript:window.open('your_url');"
```

Comment: If we want to find a control in gridview then we use this code.

 GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)((Button)sender).Parent.Parent;
        
        Label lb = (Label)gvr.FindControl("Label1");
For datalist which code we need

Comment: @AbdulRahman Ansari. The question is about how to find control in datalist why your giving code to open child window. it's not useful.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
protected void up-movie-name_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
          Label4.Text = (Datalist1.SelectedItem.FindControl("Label1").ToString());
}
```

or

```
  protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
 {
   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
   {
       LinkButton linkButton = e.Item.FindControl("LinkButton1") as LinkButton;
       string commandText = linkButton.Text;
   }
}
```